# Plotting a type of Histogram

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, histogram

I have data in the following format

```
0   0.69
1   0.87
1   0.87
0   0.87
0   0.87
```

So the first column is either zero or one. Second column is a decimal number. If you look at the table, at 0.69, there is only one zero and no ones. Also at 0.87, there are two zeros and two ones. I want to plot it so that the x-axis is the decimal number. Y-axis has two plots. One will be number of zeros at that decimal number and the other is the number of ones. Also assume that I have this table in pandas dataframe format.

Answer (score 3):

use `groupby`, `size`, and `unstack`

```
df.groupby([0, 1]).size().rename_axis([None, None]).unstack(0).plot.bar()
```

[image]